# WPF DrawingImage not showing

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently facing the Problem of styling WPF's TreeViewItem (or its expander to be precise) and when I put in an ImageSource from a PNG file it IS showing, but as expected jagged. So I replaced it with a DrawingImage and it does not appear.

[image: Screenshot]

This is the template for the Expander. Most of the code is just from the SimpleStyles.xaml included is Blend. (the TreeViewItem itself seems fine):

```
<Style x:Name="Expander" d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid Width="15" Height="13" Background="Transparent">

                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"  x:Name="IsExpandedPath">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <DrawingImage>
                                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                    <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V476,25 H806,06 V0 H0 Z">
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.25,-0.11L238.25,-0.11 238.13,0 238,-0.11z" />
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.12,806.06L238.12,806.06 238.25,806.39 238,806.36z">
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                <Pen Brush="#FF000000" Thickness="1" StartLineCap="Flat" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" MiterLimit="10" />
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.13,0L0,211.44 238.12,806.06 476.25,211.44 238.13,0z M238,353.89L73,206.89 238,59.89 403.17,206.89 238,353.89z" />
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                            </DrawingImage>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>

                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ExpandPath">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <DrawingImage>
                                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                    <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V476,25 H806,06 V0 H0 Z">
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.25,-0.11L238.25,-0.11 238.13,0 238,-0.11z" />
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.12,806.06L238.12,806.06 238.25,806.39 238,806.36z">
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                <Pen Brush="#FF000000" Thickness="1" StartLineCap="Flat" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" MiterLimit="10" />
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.13,0L0,122.057 238.12,806.06 476.25,122.057 238.13,0z M238,220.39L73,122.529 238,24.668 403.17,122.529 238,220.39z" />
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                            </DrawingImage>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>

                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="IsExpandedPath"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ExpandPath"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: @EdPlunkett thank you! It WOORKS also, I got the Geometry from a svg to xaml converter i found on github (https://github.com/BerndK/SvgToXaml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this in a stand-alone `ToggleButton`. It works for me if I delete the `ClipGeometry` attributes from the `DrawingGroup` elements:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"  x:Name="IsExpandedPath">
    <Image.Source>
        <DrawingImage>
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup >
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.25,-0.11L238.25,-0.11 238.13,0 238,-0.11z" />
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.12,806.06L238.12,806.06 238.25,806.39 238,806.36z">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Brush="#FF000000" Thickness="1" StartLineCap="Flat" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" MiterLimit="10" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.13,0L0,211.44 238.12,806.06 476.25,211.44 238.13,0z M238,353.89L73,206.89 238,59.89 403.17,206.89 238,353.89z" />
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>

<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ExpandPath">
    <Image.Source>
        <DrawingImage>
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup >
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.25,-0.11L238.25,-0.11 238.13,0 238,-0.11z" />
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.12,806.06L238.12,806.06 238.25,806.39 238,806.36z">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Brush="#FF000000" Thickness="1" StartLineCap="Flat" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" MiterLimit="10" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M476.25,806.06z M0,0z M238.13,0L0,122.057 238.12,806.06 476.25,122.057 238.13,0z M238,220.39L73,122.529 238,24.668 403.17,122.529 238,220.39z" />
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```